# Comparing strings in a graph

Tags: java, string, data-structures, graph

I have a graph representation such that each nodes contains `(int id, String categoryName)`. And it consist of approx 500,000 nodes. Right now say I would like to check if categoryName `"computing"` exist in the graph, would that mean I have to traverse through the whole graph like using BSF method? (correct me if I am wrong here). It is pretty slow now (takes up to about 3 minutes) to check if that categoryName exist, any advise on how can I improve the speed of searching and comparing of the String values?

Comment: `HashMap` from category name to node?

Comment: It depends a lot on how your graph is organized, what meaning has the `id` field.

Comment: Maybe a [graph database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_database) would be suitable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have no other data - then yes, searching the graph will be needed.

However, you can pre-process and use a [`Map<String,Node>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) (Where `Node` is your node class) that maps from the strings to your actual nodes, and quickly find if a certain `String` has a relevant node.

You can get the node from the string by using: [`map.get(string)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29)

You can use a [`TreeMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) (which has O(logn) seek & insertion time and is ordered), and a [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) (which implements a hash table and has `O(1)` average case seek & insertion time)

---

Note: this assumes no duplicates, i.e. no string has two different nodes representing it.

If this assumption is not correct, you can use something like [Guava Multimap](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)

Comment: Yes your assumption is right. Many thanks! =D i will try it out.